# Accessing ArrayList objects outside of main class to change CartesianCoordiantes

Tags: java, jframe

I'm a bit stuck trying to manipulate information stored in an ArrayList in the  main class.

My ArrayList contains a "RandomTurtleA" object called "turtles"(more turtles will be added to the ArrayList later) which extends "DynamicTurtle" which extends "Turtle". If I can change the CartesianCoordinates for the "turtles" stored in the ArrayList in Class Turtle, I can then make sure they do not leave the visible JFrame.

I have setter methods to change the CartesianCoordinates, however cannot find out how to use them outside of the Main class in the wrapPosition method where the various if statements are to check if the turtles off screen.

Here is the Main Class: (The ArrayList)

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Lab7b
{
 public static void main(String [ ] args) 
 {
  int deltaTime = 50;
  double currentX, currentY;

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas();      
  frame.setTitle("Welcome to turtle land!");
  frame.setSize(1000, 600);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.add(canvas);   
  

  JLabel hello = new JLabel("Hello all Word!");
  hello.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);    
  frame.add(hello, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);    

  
  Canvas turtleCanvas = new Canvas();
  frame.add(turtleCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);  

  ImageIcon supermanImage = new ImageIcon("superman.png");
  JLabel supermanJLable = new JLabel(supermanImage);
  frame.add(supermanJLable, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

  ImageIcon hulkImage = new ImageIcon("hulk.png");
  JLabel hulkJLable = new JLabel(hulkImage);
  frame.add(hulkJLable, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

  CartesianCoordinate randomInit = new CartesianCoordinate(400,300);  

  ArrayList<DynamicTurtle> turtles = new ArrayList<DynamicTurtle>();
  turtles.add(new RandomTurtleA(turtleCanvas, 400, 300));  

  

  while(true)
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).unDrawTurtle();
    hello.setText("X: " + (turtles.get(i)).getPositionX() + "    Y: " + (turtles.get(i)).getPositionY());
   
    (turtles.get(i)).getPositionX() = currentX; // Problems here trying to access the current position of the turtle
    (turtles.get(i)).getPositionX() = currentY; // "                                                              "   
    
    (turtles.get(i)).wrapPosition(1000, 600);
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).update(1000);
   }


   for (int i = 0; i < turtles.size(); i++)
   {
    (turtles.get(i)).drawTurtle();
   }
  
  Utils.pause(deltaTime/2);
  } 
 }
}
```

The Turtle Class: (containing the wrapPosition Method)

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Turtle 
{
protected Canvas canvas; // private field reference to a canvas private           
private CartesianCoordinate myLocation, oldLocation; 
private boolean penDown = true;
private double Angle;
public Turtle kieranMullen;

public Turtle(Canvas canvas, CartesianCoordinate initLocation) 
{
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.myLocation = new CartesianCoordinate(0,0);
    Angle = 0;
    penDown = true;
    myLocation = initLocation.copy();        
}

public void wrapPositon(double maximumXPosition, double mamimumYPosition) 
{
    if(turtles.getPositionX() < 0) //if current x of turtle is less than 0
    {
        this.setX(1000); //set to 1000
    }

    if(currentX > 1000)
    {
        this.setX(0);
    }

    if(currentY < 0)
    {
        this.setY(600);
    }

    if(currentY > 600)
    {
        this.setX(0);
    }
}

public double getPositionX()
{
    double getPosX;
    getPosX = myLocation.getX();
    return getPosX;
}

public double getPositionY()
{
    double getPosY;
    getPosY = myLocation.getY();
    return getPosY;
}

}
```

The CartesianCoordinate Class: (Containing the setter Methods)

```js
   class CartesianCoordinate
{
private double xPosition, yPosition, setterX, setterY;


public CartesianCoordinate(double x, double y)
{
 this.xPosition = x;
 this.yPosition = y;
}

public double getX()
{
 return this.xPosition;
}

public double getY()
{
 return this.yPosition;
}

public void setX(double setterX)
{
 this.setterX = xPosition;
}

public void setY(double setterY)
{
 this.setterY = yPosition;
} 

}
```

I Would greatly appreciate any help given to me, thanks in advance. Regards, Hornsbeh.

Comment: TL;DR. No body here is gonna go over all that code to find your issue. Try to give a more minimal set of code to troubleshoot.

Comment: @blahfunk thanks for the feedback, i have removed the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is, that you only have a getter for position x and y in your turtle class.

You have to add a setter for your location that is public in the Turtle class that in  turn calls the functions of your Coordinates Object. Just like you already did with the get methods.

Setter:

```
class Turtle {

    //...

    public void setPositionX(final double x)
    {
         myLocation.setX(x);
    }
```

The same for Y.

Then in your main class you can set X by using that method:

```
(turtles.get(i)).setPositionX(currentX);
```

Comment: Thank you for you're help! I have added the setters in the Turtle class. However, how would i then be able to set the CartesianCoordinates in the wrapPosition method using the if statements? I have no idea how to address this problem. Whatever "object" i address to get its x/y position from the current state in the ArrayList i get all sorts of error.  Cheers.